# Is there an automated way in VS2015 to add all the "standard" web api/MVC bits?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, visual-studio-2015

I've read a couple of times that "It doesn't matter if you don't include MVC, you can add it in later!". What I was hoping for is a way to bring up the original wizard where you select Web.API/MVC/Forms and have it create all the directories and default files.

I can't find that as an option though.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Add or Remove Programs" and try to uninstall Visual Studio. This will bring up a dialog that allows to:

- Modify
- Repair
- Uninstall

Now just click "Modify" and you'll be able to add / remove features to your Visual Studio installation. Under "Windows and Web Development" there is a "Microsoft Web Developer Tools" you want to check.

Comment: Ah no, we don't want to uninstall visual studio. Visual Studio when it creates an ASP.NET web project gives you options for including certain technologies. Once the project is created I want a way to get back to that wizard and add a technology. It's just a time saver. The standard files and directories for MVC and Web.API are numerous.